# Symfony2 middleware

Tags: php, symfony, middleware

I'm looking for a way to create a Django-like **middleware** for an application on `Symfony2`. Basically, I need to preprocess **every** `request` before it comes to `Controllers` and postprocess **every** `response` after `Controllers`, but before it comes to user.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need a middle ware for this in Symfony2.
There are things called Kernel Events.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events

You may want to have a look at kernel.request and kernel.response

Comment: I have implemented this way and it works in SF4! By implementing with Kernel Events gives more control on different levels of a request/response

Answer (score 7):

[StackPHP](http://stackphp.com) was recently launched; it provides a middleware system for anything using Symfony's `HttpKernelInterface` (Symfony, Silex, ezPublish, etc).